# findAll() HQL not returning paginated list in grails

Tags: grails, pagination

I am working on a grails application, in this I have to apply filter box on list.gsp. When I am filtering using following query(in my service) I am getting **paginated list** :

```
    def clientCriteria = TripOrder.createCriteria()
        def searchResults = clientCriteria.list(max: params.max, offset: params.offset, sort: params.sort, order: params.order){
            ilike("origin", "${searchFor}%")
        }
        println searchResults.getTotalCount()
        [searchResults: searchResults, searchResultSize: searchResults.getTotalCount()]
```

But my problem is that when I am using findAll, I am not able to get **paginated list**, query as follows :

```
def searchResults =  TripOrder.findAll("from TripOrder as t where t.status.status=:status", [status: searchFor], [max: maximum, sort: params.sort, order: params.order])

            println searchResults.size()

            [searchResults: searchResults, searchResultSize: searchResults.size()]
```

**Note** : Because of some reasons I have to use findAll() HQL instead criteria queries.

Above result provide only number of list equal to max instead of provide **paginated list**.

Please provide me solution for getting paginated list using findAll().

Thanks.

Comment: findAll does not return a paginated list, it returns an array, per the documentation: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment, you can do like this where you get a `PagedResultList`

```
def results = TripOrder.createCriteria.list(params) {
    customer {
       ilike 'firstName', "%$searchFor%" 
    }
}

assert results.size() != results.totalCount
```

It basically fires another query for the totalCount, if you want to stick to `findAll` or something like findAll instead of criteria then you can imbibe a better alternative by using a `DetachedCriteria`/`where query` which lazily executes the query on demand. Again, you won't be able to get the total count in first query. You have to fire another for the same.

```
def query = TripOrder.where {
    customer.firstName =~ searchFor
}

//Query executed only when list() is called
def results = query.list( params )

//Only executed when count() is called
def totalCount = query.count()
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for this wonderful explanation, I was looking for the solution which you provided. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`findAll` isn't designed to return a paginated list. It returns an array. This is clearly stated in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAll.html).

Comment: ..so is their only one way for getting paginated list in grails by only using criteria queries.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to compare a property of Doamin which is instance of a Domain class, for example : 
    class TripOrder { 
         Person customer
     String status
    }

    class Person {
     String firstName
     String middleName
    }
I want to compare customer.firstName property of TripOrder using criteria query, how would I achieve that. Thanks.

Comment: your given answer is seems to be correct according according to my ques. But I was looking for the solution which is provided by **dmahapatro**. Because of this I am marking his answer as correct answer and up-voting your answer.